# how to save H, R and S in object?

Tags: javascript, apex-code, visualforce

I want to save hour(h),minutes(m) and seconds(s) in object, and i try to save s(second) in object but it always save 0 in object not current value of second of timer.  And in javascript the alert box is also not working.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Time_Card__c" extensions="myTimeCard">
<apex:form >
<html>
<head>
    <title>Digital clock</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../Styles/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    <body onUnload="return returnTime()" >
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            function returnTime() {
                var closeTime = new Date();
                window.returnValue = closeTime;
                alert(returnValue);
            }
            function CloseWindow() {
                window.close();
            }
        </script></body>
    <body onload="timer()" >
    <style type="text/css">
        #time{
        font-size:20pt;
        }
        #body
        {
            background-color:#F3F3F3;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var digiclock = "00:00:00";
        i = 0;
        function timer() {
            var digiformat = "";
            if (i > 3599) {
                var H = Math.floor(i / 3600);
            }
            else {
                var H = 0;
            }

            var M = i - (H * 3600)

            if (M > 59) {
                M = Math.floor(M / 60)
            }
            else {
                M = 0
            }
            var S = i - (M * 60)
            if (H < 10) {
                H = "0" + H;
            }
            if (M < 10) {
                M = "0" + M;
            }
            if (S < 10) {
                S = "0" + S;
            }
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = H + ":" + M + ":" + S;

            setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
            i++;
             document.getElementById('ssec').innerHTML = S;
             alert("ddd");
        }

    </script>
        <table align="left" width="200px" height="100px" style="background-color:#F3F3F3;" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr >
                <td><div align="center"><center>Total Elapsed Time </center></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="center" id="time"><center>90</center></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <td> <apex:commandButton value="Stop" onclick="ssec.value=100" action="{!save}"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>

 </html>
 <apex:inputHidden value="{!Time_Card__c.Spend_Second__c}" id="ssec"/>

 </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. It has multiple body tags, html elements after the closing `</html>`. Sometimes its hard to tell what browsers and javascript interpreters do with markup like that...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an Object like:

```
    var myObj = new Object;
    myObj.h = H;

//And so on..
```

Or,

```
var myObj = {h:H ...}
```

You can easily access values from objects, like:
`myObj.h` will give you the value of `H`.